# How I can make gdb print all breakpoint executions without stopping on them?

Tags: gdb, breakpoints

Use case: I want to research program execution by reading breakpoint hits. Hits count is more than 100.

I can't use `continue 1`, because hits count is too large. I can't use `continue <some big number>`, because GDB skipping all occurrences and not writing them in log.

What I can do with this case?

Comment: Look's like I need user-defined function for this

Answer (score 0):

```
define print_all_br
  set $i = 0
  while $i < $arg0
    continue 1
    set $i = $i + 1
  end
end
```

This might work with `print_all_br(<some_big_number>)`